# Entity Not Pointing To Table

Tags: symfony

In Symfony2 I have created an Entity for table here is code snippet.[Code for Entity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kDqKq.png)
Also I have wrote a code to insert data into database.
[code that inserts data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wNVrV.png)
But while inserting it pointing to the class name as table name.
That is mapping of entity to table not working.

Any one having any guess why it is not working?

Answer (score 0):

The `@ORM\Table('instructor_venue)` annotation is missing a quotation mark.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot a **'** on the line @\ORM\Table('instructor_venue')

Answer (score 0):

```
 /** 
  * @ORM\Entity
  * @ORM\Table(name="instructor_venue")
  */
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code snippet may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion. Please also try not to crowd your code with explanatory comments, as this reduces the readability of both the code and the explanations!